# Python decorator applicable to a class that allows you to specify which methods should be debugged. How can I implement it?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm doing a project where I need to implement debugger decorators applicable to both functions and classes. To explain better I show you the code:

```
class debug(object):

  def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print()
    print(f"Calling function: {self.function}")
    print(f"args: {args}") ; print(f"kwargs: {kwargs}")
    result = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    print(f"result is: {result}")
    return result



def _debug(function):  
  def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
    print()
    print(f"Calling function: {function}")
    print(f"ARGS: {args}") ; print(f"KWARGS: {kwargs}")
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
    print(f"RESULT IS: {result}")
    return result
  return wrapper


@debug  # or @_debug
def foo(x,y):
  return x+y



class cdebug(object):
  pass



def _cdebug(...):
  pass



class pallino(object):
  
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def goo(self):
    return self.x+self.y  



@cdebug('oops', 'goo') # or @_cdebug('oops', 'goo')
class pinco(pallino):

  def __init__(self,x,y,z):
    super().__init__(x, y)
    self.z = z

  def oops(self,a):
    return self.x+self.y+self.z-a

if __name__ == '__main__':

  foo(10,20)

  p = pinco(2,5,7)

  p.oops(4)

  p.goo()
```

I had no major problems implementing the debugger decorator applicable to a function, both as a class(debug) and as a function(_debug).
But I really have no idea how I could do the debugger decorator applicable to a class, in both versions(cdebug and _cdebug). It should allow me, when I call one of the methods (e.g.: p.goo() or p.oops(..)) that have been passed to the decorator as parameters, to debug them in a similar way as the debugger decorator does for a simple function.

Comment: You need to look up how to implement a `Proxy` which can forward *any* method call to another object. During this forwarding you can print your debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a subclass, and decorate methods of the subclass. That way you do not modify the original class which can be expected from a decorator:

```
def cdebug(cls):
    class wrapper(cls):
        pass
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isfunction):
        # this one will not decorate special methods
        if not (name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')):
            setattr(wrapper,name, _debug(getattr(cls, name)))
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Being a novice I could never have had any idea that it could be implemented in this way, thank you very much! If I wanted to pass as parameters to the decorator the specific names of the methods I want to debug (e.g.: @cdebug('oops', 'goo')) , how should I do it? Regarding the version of the decorator as a class do you have any ideas?